# Change sprite color in unity using GUI button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a Unity program where I want to use a GUI button to change the color of a sprite. I have the following code in my script but I'm not sure how to change the color.

```
public GameObject WantedSprite;

private void DrawWindow(int windowID)
{
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(50, 150, 100, 50), "Change the Ball's color"))
        {
            var component = WantedSprite.GetComponent<Color>();
            component.g = Random.Range(0, 255);
            component.r = Random.Range(0, 255);
            component.b = Random.Range(0, 255);
        }
```

I'm learning Unity so that's a little of my background, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track..

The component you want to reference is the `SpriteRenderer` on the game object. This has access to, and controls the `color` property.

Make a new instance of `Color` and assign it's values (note: you may need to set `.a` (alpha) property as well to 255, if the sprite goes transparent).

Once you've constructed the color, you can then assign the SpriteRenderers color to the new one.

```
   SpriteRenderer component = WantedSprite.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

   Color newColor;

   newColor.r = Random.Range(0.00f,1.00f);
   newColor.g = Random.Range(0.00f,1.00f);
   newColor.b = Random.Range(0.00f,1.00f);
   newColor.a = 1;

   component.color = newColor;
```